# Rav Belsky's illustration on how to lean by the seder

Tags: rabbis, passover-seder-hagada, heseiba-leaning

I remember watching one of OU's Pesach webinars a few years back where Rav Belsky was asked what is the proper way to lean at the seder. Rav Belsky answered that based off an ancient (Roman) tapestry which depicts people leaning, all one has to do is prop his left hand on the table and place his head in a slightly slanted postion in his hand (he illustrated how to do it). I am looking for this video everywhere, and I even asked OU where this video is and they don't know where it is. Does anyone know where to find this video?

A picture probably similar to what Rav Belsky saw (maybe even the exact one, not sure):

[image: A painting of people in togas eating while reclining on couches.]

<sup>Mosaic of a Symposium with Asarotos Oikos. Photo: [Phoenix Ancient Art](http://www.phoenixancientart.com/).</sup>

Comment: Spin off question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81108/5323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the video that you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssZY25Fj8qE

Rav Belsky does not show the tapestry, but he leans in a manner very similar to what you described. He also tells the story of seeing a tapestry of Greco-Roman royalty leaning in this manner (at [about 1:30](https://youtu.be/ssZY25Fj8qE?t=1m28s)).

Comment: There's at least one other opinion on how you should lean. Please see: ["At the seder, unsupported mid-air leaning feels awkward. In reality, how should I recline?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56472/at-the-seder-unsupported-mid-air-leaning-feels-awkward-in-reality-how-should/81790#81790)